# Ionic 3 app with cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp. Livereload trouble

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sockets, ionic-framework

I am using [cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-tcp](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcp) in my android application. In this app I am trying to connect to TCP/IP server. Example of my code:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, createInfo => {
      let socketTcpId = createInfo.socketId;
      (<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketTcpId, "127.0.0.1", 12345, result => {
        console.log("Connected to server");
      });
    });
  } ...
```

I uploaded this code to android emulator V 7.1.1 using command:

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --emulator --livereload --consolelogs
```

During the first run my application succesfully connects to TCP/IP server. But if I will press CTRL-S and livereload process will starts, after reloading I see error and warn messages:

---

**console.warn:** Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.

**Runtime Error**

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'sockets' of undefined at HomePage.ngOnInit

---

I tried to fix it with reinstalling of plugin, removed and added android platform, I tried to use window.plugins or window.cordova.plugins, but them are undefined and solved my problem. Can you help me, please?

---

After declaration of chrome variable, code:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  NavController
} from 'ionic-angular';
declare var chrome;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, createInfo => {
      let socketTcpId = createInfo.socketId;
      chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketTcpId, "127.0.0.1", 12345, result => {
        console.log("Connected to server");
      });
    });
  }...
```

First run - all working. After livereload I see message: ReferenceError: chrome is not defined. After that if I will replace declaration of chrome:

```
} from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
declare var chrome;
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
```

it will call the Runtime error "'Home Page' declared by the module...", and after that if I will put declaration back and press CTRL-S - all will work again and I will connect to server, where am I wrong?

Comment: Most probably the plugin handle (chrome.sockets.tcp) is not attached to the window object when using livereload. I guess only the code related to ionic is re-deployed and cordova plugins are not readded.

Comment: @David, do you know how can I make plugin re-deploying?

Comment: I'm afraid it you can't with livereload. You will have to run `ionic cordova run android` everytime.

Comment: @David, it is very-very sad

Comment: Yeah livereload is always a painful thing. But you can try one thing: Add the following below your imports: `declare var chrome;` and then access it via `chrome.sockets.tcp.create(...)` without the cast to window.

Comment: @David, declaration of chrome variable made something strange. I will add information to topic, look please

Comment: David, I added new code

Comment: Well I think thats an issue with ionics livereload, there is not much you can do here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You must call it with `(<any>window)`

Example:

```
(<any>window).chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(createInfo) {
       alert('Created')
       this.listenAndAccept(createInfo.socketId);
});
```